# juju - OpenStack Charms Deployment Guide - "ERROR... failed to bootstrap model"

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

Any assistance would be much appreciated; I searched through many posts and have found no answers yet.

I have been following this guide: https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/2023.2/index.html

I have tried multiple methods using physical and virtual deployments with same error when running the following command under the "Install Juju" section: `juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=jammy --constraints tags=juju maas-one maas-controller`

> 23:57:50 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environ.go:685 attempting to acquire node in zone "default"
> 23:57:50 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:969 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "default": failed to acquire node: No available machine matches constraints: [('agent_name', ['ba18b361-58d8-41e8-8f6c-a72faa0493a9']), ('mem', ['3584']), ('tags', ['juju']), ('zone', ['default'])] (resolved to "mem=3584.0 tags=juju zone=default")
> 23:57:50 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:970 (error details: [{github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/commands.(*bootstrapCommand).Run:1068: failed to bootstrap model} {github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap.Bootstrap:748: } {github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap.bootstrapIAAS:600: } {github.com/juju/juju/provider/common.BootstrapInstance:309: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "default"} {github.com/juju/juju/provider/maas.(*maasEnviron).StartInstance:716: } {github.com/juju/juju/provider/maas.(*maasEnviron).StartInstance:711: failed to acquire node} {No available machine matches constraints: [('agent_name', ['ba18b361-58d8-41e8-8f6c-a72faa0493a9']), ('mem', ['3584']), ('tags', ['juju']), ('zone', ['default'])] (resolved to "mem=3584.0 tags=juju zone=default")}])

I have verified the following:

- memory of juju controller exceeds constraint and has 4096M of memory
- all nodes are in "default" zone
- juju controller deployed via MAAS and running 22.04 LTS
- juju controller has tag "juju" configured
- both MAAS and juju systems are able to communicate to each other

I have attached output of the above command below with `--debug` set